# Where is the PowerShell documentation for the `excel.application`?

Tags: excel, powershell

I touch PowerShell once in a leap year, and [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/) is excellent to brush up, but its a different situation entirely when it comes to modules. (Sorry, not sure what the terminology is.) There a huge amount of posts and Stackoverflow threads for specific "achieve this with PowerShell in an Excel file" but the answer don't really expand on the details; a lot can be deduced, but some date of the posts range from 2009 to 2019 so not sure what has changed (other than using trial and error, of course).

The closest I could find to an API documentation is the [Excel VBA reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel). It looks awfully close to the methods I see being mentioned all over the place, so is that it?

Comment: I don't think there is a official documentation in regards to Excel in PowerShell because it's all done through COM... The closest we have to official docs on "how to do things on Excel with PS, is the documentation on Doug Finke's module [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no Microsoft provided APIs for Excel directly.
However there are two options:

1. Use `New-Object -comobject Excel.Application` to access Excel. This
   requires that Excel is installed on the machine running the script.
   I find it quite clunky.
2. Use the publicly available module `ImportExcel`. This does not need
   Excel to be installed. Is is fairly straight-forward to use, it is
   my preferred method.

Useful links for ImportExcel

- [PowerShell Gallery: ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0)
- [Read and write Excel spreadsheets with the ImportExcel PowerShell
  module](https://4sysops.com/archives/read-and-write-excel-spreadsheets-with-the-importexcel-powershell-module/)
- [PowerShell and Excel: Yes, They Work Together](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-excel/)